# Elasticsearch: scan search vs sort by _doc

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

According to [Breaking changes in 2.1: Search changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_21_search_changes.html):

> The `scan` search type has been deprecated. All benefits from this search type can now be achieved by doing a `scroll` request that sorts documents in `_doc` order.

However, there is a huge performance gain when using `scan` search type, in Node.js (with the official client), like this search request:

```
es.client.search({
  index: 'library',
  type: 'page',
  scroll: '30s',
  search_type: 'scan',
  fields: ['page_id'],
  q: 'book_id:1681'
}, ...);
```

Instead of this request:

```
es.client.search({
  index: 'library',
  type: 'page',
  scroll: '30s',
  sort: ["_doc"],
  fields: ['page_id'],
  q: 'book_id:1681'
}, ...);
```

Both requests return 12530 documents (of course after using `scroll`). But `scan` search type takes ~1s, while `sort` in `_doc` order takes more than ~4.5s!

Could you please tell me how to achieve all benefits from scan search by sorting documents in _doc order?

**Update**: Same results in Python. `scan` search type is much faster than regular `scroll` and sort in `_doc` order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/12983#issuecomment-181118167), Adrien Grand wrote:

> How many shards do you have? I'm asking because `search_type='scan'`
>   retrieves `$size * $num_shards` docs per page, so the following would
>   be a better comparison (assuming 5 shards):
>
> ```
> es.search(index='library',
> doc_type='page',
> scroll='2m',
> search_type='scan',
> size=10,
> body='{"query":{"term":{"book_id":1681}}}')
> ```
>
> vs.
>
> ```
> es.search(index='library',
> doc_type='page',
> scroll='2m',
> size=50,
> body='{"query":{"term":{"book_id":1681}},"sort":["_doc"]}')
> ```

I tested this, and it now has the same performance as `scan`.

Comment: Hey I still get the difference between the two in terms of performance. If both are returning the same count of results why scan was faster?

Comment: According to my tests, they are the same. Try to increase `size` to 100 or so.

Comment: Size of scan or scroll?